# Let $f:(0,∞)\to\mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function such that $f'(x^2)=1-x^3$ for all $x>0$ and $f(1)=0$. Then $f(4)$ equals?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, functions

$f'(x^2)=1-x^3$
The question is easy, I got the answer by taking $y=x^2$ and solving.
But when I tried different approach by writing   $f'(x^2)=\frac{∂f}{∂x}\frac{∂x}{∂x^2}=\frac{∂f}{∂x}\frac{1}{2x}=1-x^3$,
I get same $f(x)$ as before, that is $f(x)=x^2-\frac{2x^5}{5}+c$.
So now, I should directly put the value of $x=4$ but then it gives wrong answer. Where am I going wrong in using this approach?

Comment: How do you directly calculate $f(4)$ without knowing what $c$ is?

Comment: ofcourse, i meant by first finding c using the given value then directly putting x=4.

Comment: @Levent With $y=x^2$ $f'(y)=1-y^{3/2}$ then by [FTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#Second_part): $$\,f(4)=f(1) + \int_{1}^4 f'(y) dy = 0 + \left(x-\frac{2}{5}x^{5/2}\right)\,\Bigg|_1^4$$

Answer (score 0):

In your first way, you substitute $y=x^2$, which means $f'(x^2)$ is $\frac{df}{dx}$, but evaluated at $x^2$. In your different approach, $f'(x^2)$ is interpreted as $\frac{df}{d(x^2)}$. However, taking the derivative of $f$ with respect to $x^2$ is not the same as substituting $x^2$ into $f'(x)$, so these are two different interpretations of what $f'(x^2)$. The first interpretation is what $f'(x^2)$ usually means, so the first method is correct.

Comment: no, but the answer is -47/5 which comes when we take x=2 in last step.

Comment: @Parul When I do it the other way, I get $f'(y)=1-x^{3/2}$, giving me $f(y)=x-\frac{2}{5}x^{5/2}+C$, so by plugging in $y=1^2=1$ for $x=1$, I get $C=-\frac{3}{5}$, and then plugging in $y=4^2=16$ for $x=4$, I get the same answer as I do plugging $x=4$ into the equation of my answer. Therefore, I do not see how the answer is $-\frac{47}{5}$.

Comment: no, write f(y)=f(x^2)=x-(2/5)x^5/2-3/5. then f(4)=f(2^2), which implies x=2 and hence, answer=-47/5

Comment: @Parul I am sorry for all of the confusion. Please see my new answer above.

Comment: Right. Thank you for pointing my mistake

Comment: @Parul No problem! Thank you for asking the question! It was very interesting and I also learned something!